# Possible to hide app icon in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode5

I am using XCODE 5. I have added app icon image into project. Is there a way to disable or enable app icon? Disable means do not show icon when disabled otherwise must show icon on device/simulator.

Comment: As far as I can tell (your english appears *very* broken), what you're looking for can only be done via jailbreak and a library called `libhide`. There is documentation of this package elsewehere, a simple google search would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% clear to me whether you want to hide the icon dynamically/programmatically, or not.  I didn't see that requirement explicitly, so I'm assuming you don't need programmatic control:

This **can** be done, and it does **not** require jailbreaking.

It is, however, something that Apple would reject in their App Store.  Please, however, do not equate what is not allowable in the App Store with what requires jailbreaking.  Those are not the same thing.  There are many "private" or "undocumented" features you may want to use in a hobbyist or enterprise app that doesn't get distributed through the App Store.

To hide an app's icon on the SpringBoard, add this to your Info.plist file:

```xml
  <key>SBAppTags</key>
  <array>
     <string>hidden</string>
  </array>
```

Answer (score -2):

No, You cannot hide an App icon (legally). That is, Apple does not allow such a feature and it cannot be done in Non-Jailbreak apps. You can only do this if you Jailbreak your iOS.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  Hiding the icon does not require jailbreaking.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22956329/119114).